# Unable to Push Object of UserDetails Class

Tags: android, firebase

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCdcC.png)I'm trying to push an Object to the Firebase Database,when I create an object of the "Case" class and push it it works although when I do the same for "UserDetails" class it does not work.

The Database Entry is not generated when UserDetails object is to be pushed and the app closes... It does not give any Force Close Warning.

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Login");
//myRef.child("users").setValue(new UserDetails("j","a"));//Doesn't work
myRef.child("users").setValue(new Case("j",0)); //Works
```

The  classes:

Case Class

```
public class Case {
int vote;
String option;
ArrayList<String> iwant;
public Case(){
    vote=0;
    option="";
    iwant=new ArrayList<>();
}
public Case(String o,int v){
    vote=v;
    option=o;
    iwant=new ArrayList<>();
}
public void refreshvote(){
    vote=iwant.size();
}
public void newwant(String person){
        iwant.add(person);
        refreshvote();
    }
public void rmwant(String person){
    iwant.remove(person);
    refreshvote();
}

public boolean contains(String person){
    if(!iwant.contains(person))
        return false;
    else
    return true;
    }
public String getOption(){
    return option;
}
public int getVote(){
    return vote;
  }
}
```

UserDetails Class:

```
public class UserDetails {
String uname,password;

public UserDetails(){
    uname="";
    password="";
}
public UserDetails(String u, String p){
    uname=u;
    password=p;
}
public boolean auth(String requname,String reqpass){
    if((uname.equals(requname))&&(password.equals(reqpass))){
        return true;
    }
    else
    return false;

}

}
```

The Picture above shows my console after

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Login");
myRef.child("users").setValue(new Case("j",0)); //Works
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add 2 objects with different structures under the same child. You need to use something like this:

```
myRef.child("user_details").setValue(new UserDetails("j","a"));
myRef.child("case").setValue(new Case("j",0));
```

Or if you want to have more properties to a class, add more fields to that particular class.

The problem was solved trought adding public getters to the UserDetails class.

Comment: I was using Case Just to test if Data was being sent, I have Deleted all entries of Case in "users" child before trying to Insert UserDetails.

Comment: Have you tried to add that object under a different node?

Comment: I'm a little new to this.. by new node do you mean a different child name?                           myRef.child("UserDetails").push().setValue(new UserDetails("Jai Lulla","nopass"));

Comment: I tried this and used .push() to generate a Unique id... that didn't solve the problem though

Comment: No error,no force close,the app opens after running and shuts immediately

Comment: But the data is added to the database? Have you checked in the Firebase console?

Comment: No data added to the console

Comment: That was the initial reason for me to try the Case class. With that class the app didn't close and the data appeared at the console

Comment: In the `UserDetails` you don't have public getters. Please add `getName()` and `getPassword()` methods. Does it work this time?